# Need Modeling Help For An Ordering Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'd like to create a Django project for my company's purchasing department. This would be my first project in Django, so sorry if this comes off as rudimentary. The workflow would look something like this:

user registers for an account > signs in > can create, edit, view, or delete a purchase order.

I'm getting tripped up on the modeling. Presumably I can create and authenticate users using django.contrib.auth. Also, since this is mainly a form saving/printing application I would use a ModelForm to generate my forms based on my models since the users will be making changes to the form data that will need to be saved. A simplified version of the purchase order form in question looks something like this:

```
| Vendor | Date  | Lead Time | Arrival Date | Buyer_Name |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| FooBar |1-1-12 | 30        | 2-1-12       | Mr. Bar    |
+--------+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+
+--------+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| SKU    | Description | Quantity | Price | Dimensions   |
+--------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
|12345   | Soft Bar    | 38       | 5.75  | 16 X 5 X 8   |
+--------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
|12346   | Hard Bar    | 12       | 5.75  | 16 X 5 X 8   |
+--------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
|12347   | Medium Bar  | 17       | 5.75  | 16 X 5 X 8   |
+--------+-------------+----------+-------+--------------+
```

As you can see, the main purchase order form has a header that identifies the Vendor being ordered from, the current date, lead time, arrival date, and the buyer's name who is filling the form out. Under that is a line-by-line order detail for three different SKUs. Ideally, each PurchaseOrder should be able to have many SKUs added to it.

What is the best way to model something like this? Do I create a User, PurchaseOrder, and SKU model? Then add a FK to the SKU Model that points to the PurchaseOrder Model's PK or is there some other, more correct, way to do something like this? Thanks in advance for any help.

[Edit]

Django had what I was looking for all along. Since this is essentially a nested form, I could make use of Formsets.

Here are two helpful links to get started:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: Also if you want to get a lot free out of the box and this is not just a pet project but a working product for your company try https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap. Be wary of not learning the fundamentals that pinax allows you to skip though.

Answer (score 0):

Use django's built in user model (you can look at the source to see the definition but it is similar to the code below for these other models). Other than that I would suggest a model for every object you mentioned.

Don't add a FK to the SKU Model since SKU can exist without being in a purchase order (if I understand the problem correctly).

### models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Vendor(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     #other fields

class SKU(models.Model):
     description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     #other fields

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
     purchaser = models.ForiegnKey(User)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     skus = models.ManyToManyField(SKU) #this is the magic that allows 1 purchase order to be filled with several SKUs
     #other fields
```

Comment: The SKU would only exist within a purchase order. Do you think I can define the SKU (many) to purchase order (one) with a simple FK? Then define the User model as a one-to-many with the purchase order table?

Comment: Do you think I can define the SKU (many) to purchase order (one) with a simple FK? Yes, if a SKU cannot exist without a purchase order but what I am saying is that doesn't make sense to me. I would think SKU exist and they are placed into PurchaseOrder so the relation would stand but you know the model better than I do. I also edited the relationship to include a user relationship. I put it as a PurchaseOrder has a FK to User since, using my intuition, a PurchaseOrder cannot exist without an affiliated user.